# Dividing the List of values in 2 groups in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, automation, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want to divide the list of values into two groups so that one group sum equal to A & another sum is equal to B.

the example:

[image]

In the above picture, divide these 10 values in such a way that the 1st group has sum = 19184 and the 2nd group has a sum = 35966.

The value original values should not be changed.

The answer is:

[image]

How to find the answer in excel formulas?

Comment: I would set this up in the Solver.

Answer (score 0):

With some searching, you could do it with VBA or with formulas. Try e.g. this manual: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3557-excel-find-all-combinations-that-equal-given-sum.html or https://www.get-digital-help.com/identify-numbers-in-sum-using-solver-in-excel/?PageSpeed=noscript